# Showing formatted JavaScript as content in HTML

Tags: javascript, json

Hi I am new to JavaScript and I need to show this JavaScript object (pseudo-JSON) into a div on a HTML page, I can't use jQuery can anyone help please.

```
var data = {
    "music": [
        {
        "id": 1,
        "artist": "Oasis",
        "album": "Definitely Maybe",
        "year": "1997"
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? You may want to visit the [tour] and the [help]

Comment: 1) Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. 2) [This isn't JSON.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/6303733)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure which data you want to show in the `div`. `data` is an `object` while `music` is a key to `data`. `data.music` will return the music array. Then use `forEach` array method to loop through the array.

Hope this snippet will be useful

```
var data = {
    "music": [
        {
        "id": 1,
        "artist": "Oasis",
        "album": "Definitely Maybe",
        "year": "1997"
        },
    ]
}

var _getData = data.music // will return music array;
_getData.forEach(function(item){
document.write('<pre>'+item.id+'</pre>')
})
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/we69qpjr/)

Comment: I was missing the object reference, this was very helpful.

Comment: @Sublize happy to help. `document.write` was use just for demonstration in your application you must use **innerHTML** to populate the div

Answer (score 1):

If you want your data to be properly formatted, [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) will natively do this for you. So in the example below, you can see we pass in the data (ignore the second argument, this is a replacer function to parse the string) and the number of formatting spaces required (in this case 2).

```js
var data = {
  "music": [{
    "id": 1,
    "artist": "Oasis",
    "album": "Definitely Maybe",
    "year": "1997"
  }, ]
};


document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = '<pre><code>' + JSON.stringify(data, null, 2) + '</code></pre>';
```

```css
pre {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```

`document.getElementById('target').innerHTML` sets the html content of an element with `id="target";

The `<pre>` tag preserves whitespace formatting and the `<code>` tag tells the browser to render as is.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function output(inp) {
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('pre')).innerHTML = inp; }

function syntaxHighlight(json) {
    json = json.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
    return json.replace(/("(\\u[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}|\\[^u]|[^\\"])*"(\s*:)?|\b(true|false|null)\b|-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?)/g, function (match) {
        var cls = 'number';
        if (/^"/.test(match)) {
            if (/:$/.test(match)) {
                cls = 'key';
            } else {
                cls = 'string';
            }
        } else if (/true|false/.test(match)) {
            cls = 'boolean';
        } else if (/null/.test(match)) {
            cls = 'null';
        }
        return '<span class="' + cls + '">' + match + '</span>';
    }); }

var obj = {a:1, 'b':'foo', c:[false,'false',null, 'null', {d:{e:1.3e5,f:'1.3e5'}}]}; var str = JSON.stringify(obj, undefined, 4);

output(str); output(syntaxHighlight(str));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use dot notation. See code below

```
var data = {
    "music": [
        {
        "id": 1,
        "artist": "Oasis",
        "album": "Definitely Maybe",
        "year": "1997"
        },
    ]
};

$('p').text(data.music[0].artist);
```

[See jsfiddle attached](https://jsfiddle.net/t0a02baj/1/)

Comment: Thank you i was missing the object reference, in the work i was doing, obviously just a silly mistake.

Answer (score -1):

Your JS be like

```
var data = {
    "music": [
        {
        "id": 1,
        "artist": "Oasis",
        "album": "Definitely Maybe",
        "year": "1997"
        },
    ]
}

var item = data.music;
  for(var i = 0; i<item.length; i++){
  document.write(item[i].id + ", " + item[i].artist);
  document.write(item[i].album);
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/we69qpjr/2/)